# PHP in_array not working - incorrect second datatype but passing an array

Tags: php, html

I'm using an if else to display various submenus depending on whether a user is logged in or not.

I know I can do this with a

```
if( ($currentPage == userSettings.php) || ($currentPage == .....ETCETCETC) )
```

but I thought it would be cleaner to pop the url's into an array and then just search to see if the current page was within that array.

```
<?php

$memberArray = array("userProfile.php","userHome.php","userSettings.php",
"userAccount.php","userChangePassword");

}else if( in_array($currentPage , $memberArray) ){
?>
```

However when I run the code and reload the page I receive an error saying that datatype is wrong

EDIT: Error message included and code 'formatted to use 4 lines instead of two.

> Warning: in_array() [function.in-array]: Wrong datatype for second argument in /home/a6696695/public_html/include/sidebar.php on line 16

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: Unfortunately, @SteveGreen has a very good point. Only ask questions that you tried to answer yourself, and reflect the effort in your post. It takes all of 15 seconds to debug this kind of problem.

Comment: I did try and solve the issue, I couldn't see the wood for the trees type of thing

Answer (score 1):

You set `$memberArray` in if statement and using `in_array` function in else. So if it goes in else `$memberArray` is not set yet.

Comment: I'm still having issues with it but I can work through those, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

From your code, it looks like the $memberArray might be getting set inside the previous if block, like so:

```
if (whatever) {
    $memberArray = array();
} else if (in_array($currentPage, $memberArray) {

}
```

But if `(whatever)` is not true, then `$memberArray` will not be set when running `else if`. If this is the case, declare `$memberArray` before the whole thing:

```
$memberArray = array();
if (whatever) {

} else if (in_array($currentPage, $memberArray) {

}
```